# Change timezone in android device?

Tags: android, adb

I would like to change the time and timezone settings through adb shell. I have found out that i can change the time using

```
adb shell date -s YYYYMMDD.HHmmss
```

I however cannot find out how to change the timezone.

I have a device running on android 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Get current global time zone:

```
adb shell settings get global time_zone
```

Set a time zone:

```
adb shell settings put global time_zone Europe/Madrid
```

Time zones list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score -1):

Found this on stackover flow. Hope  it helps:

I changed 2 files to change my timezone.

the one that i don't entire know if it's necessary, but it keeps things in sync:

/etc/timezone
the more one you for sure need to change:

/etc/localtime
from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-tz-environment-variable/ you can determine the name of the timezone you want with tzselect.

I took inspiration from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-date-and-time-timezone-in-freebsd/ and copied my timezone file from /usr/share/zoneinfo/ to /etc/localtime.

/etc/timezone is a text file with the name of the timezone. so i just updated it to match the value provided by tzselect.

Comment: Yes, actually I also saw this but there doesnt seem to be files/directories named timezone or localtime under etc folder in my device. maybe this answer is for a different android version?

Comment: This answer is not for an Android device. This is generic Unix advice.